# Is it possible to use nested resource in case of POST?

Tags: http, rest, playframework, playframework-2.2, nested-routes

I use Play Framework 2.2.X.

Is it possible to map this route?:

```
POST /api/constructors/:constructorId/cars  CarCrudController.create(constructorId)
```

I get a `BadRequest` (code 400) when hitting this route.

IMO, it seems that Play allows nested resources only for reads: **GET** instead of **POST**.

Is it possible?

Comment: I've just found some hints about: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/iR9yNwU-bSI but no strict answer.

Comment: I think your problem may be elsewhere. I don't see any reason not to have that kind of URL. I have for example /teacher/:schoolId/upload which works. Make sure that one of your other URLs it not obscuring it?

Comment: @wwkudu Can you post a Gist with a simple example which would work?

Comment: Not sure what all to publish - can I suggest you publish what's not working and we can look at it?

Comment: @wwkudu Thanks, I succeeded to make it work. Was a bad configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested routes are supported in any HTTP method. You can checkout the [samples from the github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples) for some examples. The computer-database example, has the following routes.conf:

```
# Delete a computer
POST    /computers/:id/delete       controllers.Application.delete(id:Long)
```

The bad request response could be related with the content-type of your request or the post content itself, and nothing to do with the nested routes.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was using Restangular (JS library) in order to call my backend with this kind of nested routes. Fixed it and it works ;)